# Passing Data from Fragment to Activity in Android

Tags: android-fragmentactivity

I am using a Fragment as my first screen , I have a button which Onclick has to take to me different activity.

Here is my Code:

HomeFragment.Java:

```
package info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
//        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
//            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
//        } else {
//            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
//                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
//        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.XML

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.fragment.HomeFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Activity.JAVA

```
package info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.R;

public class ChoseFoodCourt extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            // finish the activity
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I have also added the activity in manifest file.
Please help me out adding onclick listener in HomeFragment.JAVA. Not sure where to call onclick listener.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Please help me out adding button onclick listener in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code from [developers.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). There you also will find an explanation how the OnClickListener works.

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
 }
```

}